ipywidgets properties not updated in Colab
I'm running the following code:
button = widgets.ToggleButton(description='Button')
display.display(button)
for i in range(100):
  print(button.value)
  time.sleep(0.5)

No matter how many times I toggle the button, the value that is printed is always False, even though button.value is True if I try to print it in the next cell. How can I fix this?

In your example, you wanted a loop iterating for a set amount of cycles to respond...
The problem with your implementation though is a for loop is blocking for ipywidgets' event loop, see here.
This works with asyncio to do more or less what your code snippet seemed to want to do:
import asyncio
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import time

button = widgets.ToggleButton(description='Button')
output = widgets.Output()
display(button, output)

async def update_status():
    for i in range(100):
        with output:
            clear_output()
            print(f"Iteration: {i+1} / 100")
            print(f"Button Value: {button.value}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)  # Use asyncio.sleep for asynchronous delay

asyncio.ensure_future(update_status());

Google's Gemini drafted that after I prompted it with your snippet (& discussion of getting value from toggleButton, see section below) and pointed out the for loop would be blocking and not allow the value change to show up.
You don't say why you want to do this though and it may very well be there is a better approach compatible with ipywidgets and modern browser-based event loops. You may wish to refer to other discussions referencing there (or related stuff here or here) to avoid making an XY problem for yourself.

Related Helpful Aside that came up on the journey:
In case it helps others, here is a complete simple example to respond to clicks to in modern Jupyter. (It also addresses that to handle output properly you have to channel it and that JupyterLab is the best for debugging. For all these reasons, I'm leaving it here even though the answer above more directly gets at the OP's issue.)
I don't use Google Colab; however, in modern Jupyter this works to toggle the value:
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

# Create a ToggleButton widget with an initial value of False
toggle_button = widgets.ToggleButton(value=False, description='Toggle Me')

# Create an output widget to display the value
output = widgets.Output()

# Display the widgets
display(toggle_button, output)

# Define a function to be called when the button's value changes
def on_toggle_change(change):
    with output:
        clear_output()  # Clear previous output
        print(f"New value: {change['new']}") 

# Observe changes to the button's value and call the function
toggle_button.observe(on_toggle_change, names='value')

It came from Google's Gemini with some coaxing to have the output go to the output area of the cell instead of JupyterLab's Log Console. (When working with ipywidgets, JupyterLab is best used when debugging because of the Log Console access.)
